# Mandatory Code Review in VSTS

Tags: asp.net-web-api, tfs, visual-studio-2017, azure-devops

We are migrating our project in VSTS and we are having a hierarchy in our team. Is it possible that developers can check-in the code only after their team lead reviews the code.
Before a developer Check-in, a notification/email is triggered to team lead with the detail of changeset, and after the approval/review comment only he can check-in.

I am using Visual Studio 2017, TFS and VSTS.

Comment: Have you looked at Code Review support? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/get-code-reviewed-vs I would also suggest looking into migrating to Git. I understand that's a big step but the Git support in VSTS is really great and with support for pull requests it's easy to setup the workflow you're looking for.

Comment: Hi, thanks for suggestion, yes in Git I am aware that we have a pull request.

But organisation is looking to work with TFS and VSTS.

Comment: You are migrating your project to VSTS and your company wants to add a review cycle in the process. Use this opportunity to change source control! It’s the right time. Other alternatives with TFSVC are too limited / cumbersome in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

For TFVC, you can use third-party check-in policy such as [Colin's ALM Checkin Policies VS 2017](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ColinD.ColinsALMCheckinPoliciesVS2017) which works on your VS client (See [How to utilize Team Foundation Server check-in policies](https://knowledgebase.apexsql.com/how-to-utilize-team-foundation-server-check-in-policies/)). But it's **client side** policy, that means you need to apply the policy to each client.

So, to enforce/Mandatory the Code Review, you need to write the **Server side** policy. Just reference this article: [How to Enforce Check-In Policies](https://gordonbeeming.xyz/blogs/dev/2014/1/how-to-enforce-check-in-policies) and [TFS Server-side check-in policy for git repositories](http://almsports.net/tfs-server-side-check-in-policy-for-git-repositories/1025/) to write your own check in policy.

For Git, it's more easier by setting the branch policies to force code review:

Enable `Require a minimum number of reviewers` and add the team lead as the required reviewer under `Require a minimum number of reviewers`

Refer to [Improve code quality with branch policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/git/branch-policies) for details.

Comment: @Yatin Batra Have you resolved the issue? any update?

Comment: Any sever side policy documentation from MSFT or that isnt otherwise link rotten?

Answer (score 0):

TFVC supports a Code Review workflow (although it's generally considered vastly inferior to the Git pull request/branch policy model, with good reason). There's no good way to make it mandatory, however. You can apply a third-party check-in policy, but the caveat is that check-in policies work only within Visual Studio and are relatively easy to circumvent by a determined individual.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Colin's ALM Checkin Policies VS 2017](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ColinD.ColinsALMCheckinPoliciesVS2017) for team foundation version control.